# Textbox Highlighting Always Starting at 0

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox

This is really annoying.

I have basic textboxes which do not allow highlighting of single words/characters. Every time I try to select single words/characters, the highlight immediately jumps to the front of the box and highlights everything up to where I clicked.

```
<TextBox Name="txtTaskName" AutoWordSelection="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding TaskName, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxWidth="300" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoWordSelection="False"` on your `TextBox`

```
<TextBox AutoWordSelection="False"/>
```